# Using Powershell to Modify AD First Names and Last Names to fit a standard naming convention

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am new to PowerShell.

I am looking for a way to use a powershell script to modify names in AD to a standard convention.
For example, if a last name in AD is O'Connor how would I make a rule that removes all apostrophes from all names in AD?

Additionally, if a name is hyphenated, such as Connor-McGregor how would I remove the hyphenation and everything to the left of that hyphen using powershell?

Thank you for the help in advance. If you have any recommendations on resources to better learn PowerShell scripting, please drop them as well.

This is how usernames are created. The names are pulled from a CSV file.
I need to be able to modify MiddleInitial, UserFirstname, and UserLastName to not have special characters for when their login credentials are created.

```
foreach ($User in $Users)           
{            
    $MiddleInitial = $User."student.middleName"
    $UserFirstname = $User."student.firstName"            
    $UserLastname = $User."student.lastName"
}
```

Comment: possibly you could normalize the string and then remove any character that is not `a` to `z`: `$string.Normalize([System.Text.NormalizationForm]::FormD) -replace '[^a-z]'`. i.e.: `"Connor-McGregor O'Connor ñøæ".Normalize([System.Text.NormalizationForm]::FormD) -replace '[^a-z]'` becomes `ConnorMcGregorOConnorn`

Comment: Im glad it helped. Feel free to post it as an answer to help future readers ;)